# how the precedence and associativity works in the following example?

Tags: c, operator-keyword

```
int i=3,j=1,k=0,m;
m=++i || ++j && ++k;
printf("%d%d%d%d",i,j,k,m);
```

//output is 4 1 0 1`enter code here`
//can anyone explain why k=0 and j=1 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m = ++i || ++j && ++k;`  is grouped as `m = ++i || (++j && ++k);` since, `&&` has higher precedence. But, they are evaluated from left to right.

Since, `++i = 4`, which a non-zero number, the right hand expression is not evaluated. I mean `(++j && ++k)` is not evaluated since, left hand expression result is non-zero.

For A||B, if A = 1, then results is always 1, irrespective of the value of B.

Since, the right hand expression is not evaluated, the values of `j` and `k` remain same.

This feature is called "[Short Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)".

Answer (score 0):

Precedence and associativity only affect how operators are grouped with operands - they do not affect the order in which expressions are evaluated.  Both `||` and `&&` force left-to-right evaluation.  Also, remember that the `&&` and `||` operators *short-circuit* as follows:

- In the expression `a || b`, `b` will only be evaluated if `a` evaluates to zero
- In the expression `a && b`, `b` will only be evaluated if `a` evaluates to non-zero

The expression

```
++i || ++j && ++k
```

is *parsed* as

```
(++i) || ((++j) && (++k))
```

and is *evaluated* as follows:

1. `++i` is fully evaluated and all side effects applied;
2. The *result* of `++i` is `4`, which is non-zero;
3. The `||` does not evaluate the right operand if the left operand is non-zero, so `++j && ++k` is not evaluated at all;

When everything is said and done, only `i` is updated, `j` and `k` are not.

Comment: Do we have any rule for the groping ? is it always from right to left we need to group ?

Comment: @gajanankaknale:  Grouping is controlled by precedence and associativity.  `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so `a || b && c` is grouped as `a || ( b && c)`.  Both `&&` and `||` are left-associative, so `a || b || c` is grouped as `(a || b) || c`.